# Darkflow without GPU on Jupyter-Notebook - Simple Code Required

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, darkflow

I am unable to setup & run a simple darkflow program. Infact can't even configure darkflow library:

```py
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
==> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow'
```

My Target is to run the following program:

```py
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import cv2

options = {"model": "cfg/yolo.cfg", "load": "bin/yolo.weights", "threshold": 0.1}

tfnet = TFNet(options)

imgcv = cv2.imread("./test/dog.jpg")
result = tfnet.return_predict(imgcv)
print(result
```

Please suggest steps so that I could configure darkflow on Jupyter Notebook (with no GPU) and run the above code

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by creating the file in ipynb file in darkflow directory (downloaded from github) and executing the following from the notebook:

```py
!python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
!pip install -e .
!pip install .
```